# Invoke a callback directly or return the callback

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I see return being used to invoke callbacks, especially if the callback contains an error.

Let's say I have code like:

```
function one(cb) {
  // Call some service and wait for the response, but let's take the following as an example
  if (2+2 === 4) {
    cb(null);
  } else {
    // this vs return cb(false);
    cb(false);
  }
  console.log("test");
}

one(function(error) {
  if (error)
    console.log(error);
});
```

When would returning a callback actually make sense and be useful?

Comment: This question could just say 'should a function use a return statement`. The fact that a cb function is being used to generate that value doesn't really matter. Basically if you need `var retval = cb(); return retval;` you could just run `return cb();`.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it also on jsfiddle adding console.log("test");. When I "return" the callback, that stops the execution of the rest of the code. So if the cb contains an error, it's good that I return it in many cases I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a way you can see the difference between using return, or not:

```
var one = function(cb) {
  // Call some service and wait for the
  // response, but let's take the following as an example
  if (2+2 === 4) {
    cb(true);
  }
  if (2+3 !== 4){
    cb(false);
  }
  console.log("test");
};

one(function(val) {
  if (val === true){

   setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('true');
    },
    1000);

  }
  if (val === false){

   console.log('false');   
  }
});
```

this outputs `false` `test` then one second later `true`

if you change the first conditional inside the `one` function to:

```
if (2+2 === 4) {
  return cb(true);
}
```

What do you notice?

The output is nothing for one second, and then just `true`.
Why? Because using `return` in a function signifies that you want to do that final action, and then jump out of the function execution context. No further code is run in that function.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it is used in asynchronous programming; when the result my take some time to reach, an approach is often taken to make the function "call back" through a callback when it has (finally) completed. This allows the caller of the function in question to continue performing actions whilst waiting for the return value.

Therefore, using a callback would "make sense and be useful" when the task the function is performing could take a (relatively) long time to complete. You may very well have seen callbacks commonly used when making AJAX requests. An asynchronous approach is taken here to allow the caller to continue running other JavaScript to react to whatever event triggered it. If a synchronous approach was taken, you would likely see the page/JavaScript hanging whilst waiting for the response for the AJAX request.

Callbacks are also useful for defining handlers for multiple outcomes of a function. For example, jQuery allows the user to specify individual callbacks to be executed if its AJAX function fails, succeeds, or is aborted.

To answer your question about using `return cb(ev)` or similar:

> That said, it is critical that a Return statement is also used in an asynchronous workflow in order to ensure that multiple callbacks are not invoked accidentally.

(Taken from [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2323-use-a-return-statement-when-invoking-callbacks-especially-in-a-guard-statement.htm))

Although I might have a hard time coming up with an example for it, for one reason or another it may be desirable for the function caller to have a "flag" raised which could be set through the callback. Perhaps if this function (the one which is using `return cb(ev)`) is returning to the *internals* of a "helper function", this `return` might trigger another procedure such as a clean-up, which is handled *after* the callback has been triggered.

Comment: But why do return cb(error) instead of cb(error), in both cases the code inside the call back gets invoked.

Comment: Ok I see, stops execution of the next code... So if there is an error, I may want to prevent console.log("test"); to execute. So I `return cb(error)`;

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer with what I was going to leave as a comment.

Answer (score -2):

I'm no sure, but I think that the callback function is not the best pattern for the behavior in your sample.

A better pattern for this behavior is Promises. See a good tutorial :http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: Although your provided link may answer the question, the community generally agrees that answers should contain at the very least a summary of what you're linking to, rather than *only* directing the users to the answer.

Comment: That and you didn't really answer the question.